# Can you discard a scoring card to the Space Track 6 power in Twilight Struggle?

Tags: twilight-struggle

Space Track 6 gives you this power:

> Upon reaching space 6 (Eagle/Bear has Landed), the player may discard their Held Card at the end of the turn

Scoring cards cannot be held, and you are supposed to lose if you hold it at the end of the turn, but can you discard a scoring card to this power before you lose?

I'm guessing "no" since the power says "discard their Held card", implying that the scoring card is already held and therefore you lose first, but would like to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you can not discard a scoring card to the Eagle/Bear has Landed ability since you already lost if you hold a scoring card in this situation.

from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/twilightstruggle/comments/5h7ejn/space_race_discarding_a_held_card/):

> If you check the turn sequence, checking for a **held scoring card comes before the end of a turn**. The discard a card space race power is explicitly at the end of the turn. So, you can't discard a scoring card on the space race because you lose for holding it before being able to do so.

Comment: BGG thread agrees: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1381708/can-you-discard-scoring-card-if-you-have-reached-e